# The response time is decreasing for some tasks

Tags: python

I've written a code which is supposed to receive some images and make them black & white. I'm measuring the response time for each task (response time = the time each image is received and is turned to black & white). Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
from select import select
import socket
from struct import pack
from struct import unpack
#from collections import deque
import commands
from PIL import Image
import time

host = commands.getoutput("hostname -I")
port = 5005
backlog = 5
BUFSIZE = 4096
queueList = []
start = []
end = []
temp = []

def processP(q):
    i = 0
    while q:
        name = q.pop(0)
        col = Image.open(name)
        gray = col.convert('L')
        bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<128 else 255, '1')
        bw.save("%d+30.jpg" % (i+1))
        end.append(time.time())
        #print(temp)
        i = i + 1


class Receiver:
    ''' Buffer binary data from socket conn '''
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn
        self.buff = bytearray()

    def get(self, size):
        ''' Get size bytes from the buffer, reading
            from conn when necessary 
        '''
        while len(self.buff) < size:
            data = self.conn.recv(BUFSIZE)
            if not data:
                break
            self.buff.extend(data)
        # Extract the desired bytes
        result = self.buff[:size]
        # and remove them from the buffer
        del self.buff[:size]
        return bytes(result)

    def save(self, fname):
        ''' Save the remaining bytes to file fname '''
        with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
            if self.buff:
                f.write(bytes(self.buff))
            while True:
                data = self.conn.recv(BUFSIZE)
                if not data:
                    break
                f.write(data)

def read_tcp(s):
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connected with', *addr)
    # Create a buffer for this connection
    receiver = Receiver(conn)
    # Get the length of the file name
    name_size = unpack('B', receiver.get(1))[0]
    name = receiver.get(name_size).decode()
    # Save the file
    receiver.save(name)
    conn.close()
    print('saved\n')
    queueList.append(name)
    print('name', name)
    start.append(time.time())
    if (name == "sample.jpg"):
        print('------------ok-------------')
        processP(queueList)
        print("Start: ", start)
        print('--------------------------')
        print("End: ", end)
        while start:
            temp.append(end.pop(0) - start.pop(0))
        print('****************************')
        print("Start: ", start)
        print('--------------------------')
        print("End: ", end)
        print("Temp: ", temp)
        i = 0
        while i < len(temp)-1:
            if (temp[i]<temp[i+1]):
                print('yes')
            else:
                print('No')
            i = i + 1

def read_udp(s):
    data,addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
    print("received message:", data)

def run():

    # create tcp socket
    tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcp.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    try:
        tcp.bind((host,port))
    except socket.error as err:
        print('Bind failed', err)
        return
    tcp.listen(1)

    # create udp socket
    udp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
    udp.bind((host,port))

    print('***Socket now listening at***:', host, port)
    input = [tcp,udp]

    try:
        while True:
            inputready,outputready,exceptready = select(input,[],[])

            for s in inputready:
                if s == tcp:
                    read_tcp(s)
                elif s == udp:
                    read_udp(s)
                else:
                    print("unknown socket:", s)

    # Hit Break / Ctrl-C to exit
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nClosing')
        raise

    tcp.close()
    udp.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Now for some evaluation purposes, I send a single image many times. When I look at the response times I see that sometimes the response time of the 8th image, for example, is more than the response time of the 9th one.

So my question is that since the size and the time needed for processing each of images are the same (I'm sending a single image several times), Why is the response time for each image variable? Shouldn't the response time of the next image be longer (or at least equal) that the previous one (For example, the response time for 4th image > the response time for 3rd image)?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data: copy and paste as text then format it as code.  [You should not post code as an image because:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)
[Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @wwii My console does not have the copy option, this is why I uploaded the photo, but OK I will type the output. About your second question, what is ambiguous about my question for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list contains the actual elapsed time it took for each image processing call. This value will be influenced by many things, including the amount of load on the system at that time.

When your program is running, it does not have exclusive access to all of the resources (cpu, ram, disk) of the system it's running on. There could be dozens, hundreds or thousands of other processes being managed by the OS vying for resources. Given this, it is highly unlikely that you would ever see even the same image processed in the *exact* same amount of time between two runs, when you are measuring with sub-second accuracy. The amount of time it takes can (and will) go up and down with each successive call.

Comment: I was not running any other process at the time, so you mean underlying processes? So isn't there any way to measure the time precisely?